# Create List input checked array for posting REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've used .push() to create "List" input checked array for posting REST API. But it doesn't seem right.

When unchecking, the item in array is not removed automatically. Anybody have a better solution, pls help me! Tks

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0YggxvVN1epIMWAdtiU?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could do this... it works. Can't say this is the best solution though

```
 $scope.$watch('lists', function(lists){
    $scope.count = 0;
    angular.forEach(lists, function(list){
      if(list.checked){
        $scope.count += 1;
        if (inputsList.indexOf(list.id) == -1) {
            inputsList.push(list.id);
        };
      } else {
          inputsList.pop(list.id);
      }
    })
  }, true);
```

Same logic, but, modified a lil

index.html (added ng-click)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list_id[]" ng-model="list.checked" value="{{list.id}}" ng-click='updateItem(list)' />
```

app.js (removed $scope.$watch and...)

```
$scope.currentSelectedItem = [];      
$scope.updateItem = function(item) {
    if(item.checked) {
        $scope.currentSelectedItem.push(item);
    } else {
        $scope.currentSelectedItem.pop(item);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I tried & it didn't work well.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0YggxvVN1epIMWAdtiU?p=preview

Comment: weird the plunkr link u gave above does works for me (when unchecking, List checked array gets updated)

Comment: Do u have a better solution?